# Regex replace multiple non empty lines

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

So I need to read a js file as string and replace whatever inside [] with other data.

Original

```
const array = [
   'text_a',
   'text_b',
];
```

And the output needs to be

```
const array = [
   'replacing_text_a',
   'replacing_text_b',
   'replacing_text_c',
];
```

I tried multiple things and the closest I got was

`const[ ]{0,}array[ ]{0,}=[ ]{0,}\[([\s\S]{0,})];`

but I get `Unmatched ')'`

Comment: The pattern itself seems ok, but currently you capture what is in between, but you could capture what is around the brackets and use that in the replacement. `(const\s*array\s*=\s*\[)[^]*(];)` https://regex101.com/r/E8ZIRo/1

Comment: I have several questions / comments : Is it normal the first array has no `text_c` ? You could replace the `[ ]{0,}` by `\s*` for more clarity I think. You escaped an opening bracket `\[` but not its closing one `]`. The [\s\S]{0,} will match everything till the end of the file I think, is that what you want ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird The replacing_texts are being passed into the function that handles the replacement and I need to replaced those

Comment: @Leyffda Yes, consider a two line text needs to be replaced by an array of 10 items joined together. The closing bracket does not necessarily need to be escaped. 
 [\s\S]{0,} is followed by ];, so it will stop when it hits there, and wont go to the end of the line

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/lDkKxd/2 and https://regex101.com/r/lDkKxd/2/codegen?language=javascript

Comment: @shwz Yes exactly, so you match where the replacement should go, and you capture in 2 groups all around that you want to keep. See the second link from Wiktor Stribiżew's comment for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the following regex to group the surrounding

`(const\s+array\s*=\s*\[)[^]*(];)`

https://regex101.com/r/lDkKxd/2

https://regex101.com/r/lDkKxd/2/codegen?language=javascript